# Hiding HTML media when printing

Tags: html, css, printing-web-page

I am currently working on a printable document using HTML which will display data pulled from a database. The idea is that I will use HTML/CSS to make the document look nice, but it will be exclusively for printing.

The document is laid out using tables to control how the data from the database appears.

One of the key requirements is that the document must only cover 2 sides of A4. However, the data we get from the database is somewhat unpredictable, as the field sizes are very large, so we can't guarantee that one row from the database will equal one row in the document.

THerefore, we want to use a solution where the size of the table is controlled by HTML and any output from the database that causes the table to be larger than defined should be hidden.

I've got the following CSS style defined

```
table.noQual
{
page-break-inside: avoid;
width: 100%;
border: 0px;
font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";color:black;
overflow-y:hidden;
display:block;
max-height:50px !important;
}
```

This works perfectly on screen, but when I print, all the database content is displayed, so the tables become larger than 50px and go over the page.

How can I make the content hidden from the printer as well as the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified a print stylesheet, or a print `@media` section inside your existing stylesheet?

By default a stylesheet will work on-screen fine (as you've have discovered); However unless you explicitly specify a print CSS Stylesheet, when printing the page out, it will default to the browsers default styling (usually 15pt Times New Roman etc.).

**Solution 1: Add a second, print stylesheet**

Include both tags below in your HTML head:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screenstyles.css" media="screen" />`
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printstyles.css" media="print" />`

Then copy the required formatting styles from `screenstyles.css` to `printstyles.css` (or just make both `<link rel="" />`'s link to your screen stylesheet).

**Solution 2: Only 1 stylesheet, but has print `@media` in it**

Your single CSS stylesheet would like like this (omit the `media=""` from your css link rel tag:

```
/*Normal css*/
table.noQual {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: "Verdana","sans-serif";
    color:black;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: block;
    max-height:50px !important;
}
@media print {
    /*Everything inside here will be used to style the printed product*/
    table.noQual {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        width: 100%;
        border: 0px;
        font-family: "Verdana","sans-serif";
        color:black;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        display: block;
        max-height: 50px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the actual data is, or what format it's in, it's hard to provide a solution. You may want to put some javascript in to truncate the text after a set number of characters. (I've been told there's some [nonstandard] CSS that can do the same.)

Otherwise I think your issue arises from your use of pixel height on your table. You'll probably want to use `cm` or similar units that translate to "real world" measurements. [Here's](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html) some information you may want to consider about styling for print media.

You may also want to look into using [media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) to create custom CSS exclusively for printing.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Javascript due to the way the HTML is generated by the database application, but effectively that is what I want to do, truncate the text after a number of characters is reached.

Comment: Sorry pressed <enter> too soon. The actual data is just text characters (nvarchar fields), nothing special. Thanks for the website though, i'll have a good look at it